# Prove that $2^{3n+1} + 5$ is a multiple of 7 for all n ≥ 0.

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

As the title states I need to prove that $(2^{3n+1}+5)$ is a multiple of 7 for all $n \geq 0$.

I can do this using induction but I also want to prove it using modular arithmetic. So here's what I've got so far.

Start with Fermat's little theorem: 
\begin{align}2^6 &\equiv 1 \ \ \pmod{7} \\ 2^3 \cdot 2^3 &\equiv 1 \ \ \pmod{7} \\8 \cdot 2^3 &\equiv 1 \ \ \pmod{7}  \\ 2^3 &\equiv 1 \ \ \pmod{7} \\ 2^{3n} &\equiv 1^n \pmod{7} \end{align}

I feel up to this point everything is correct.

How would I add the $1$ to the exponent? 
\begin{align} 2^{3n+1} &\equiv 1^n (5)  \pmod{7} \\ 2^{3n+1} &\equiv 5 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \pmod{7}
\end{align}
Now adding the $5$, I am confused as to how to do that as well. I would just subtract the $5$ remainder correct? Such that:

$2^{3n+1}  -5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$   but this is not what I intend to do.

I need,  $2^{3n+1} +5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$

Comment: You can use `\mod` or `\pmod` to correctly format your work.

Comment: Without modular arithmetic: $\color{red}{2^{3n+1}} \color{blue}{+5}=\color{red}{2 \cdot 8^n} \color{blue}{- 2 + 7} = 2\cdot(8^n-1)+ 7 = 2\cdot(8-1)(8^{n-1}+8^{n-2}\dots+1)+7=7 \cdot (\dots)\,$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much quicker way to do it:

Notice that $2^{3n+1} = 2^{3n} \cdot 2 = 8^n \cdot 2$. Since $8 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, we have $1 * 2 + 5 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, which is clearly true.

Comment: That is much easier. Thank you for another insight.

Comment: Why does the 8^n turn to 1 but the 2 is left alone?

Comment: Never mind 2 is 2 mod 7. AND 2 is -5 mod 7

Comment: @Tito In fact, any number in the form $7n+2$ is $2 \pmod 7$. When $n=0$, we get $2$, and when $n=-1$, we get $-5$.

Answer (score 1):

When you add $1$ to the exponent on $2$ you multiply by $2$, not by $5$ or $-2$.  So $2^{3n+1}\equiv 1×2\bmod 7$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: Could you clarify slightly?  I was thinking 2= 5 mod 7   when really  2 = -5 mod 7.  Am I correct? So then I would multiply by -5 instead of positive 5.

Comment: Yup $2\equiv -5\bmod 7$.